# Nuxt 3 Authentication Strategies with OIDC

Tags: nuxt.js, openid-connect, nuxtjs3

We have kicked off a project with Nuxt3, but one of the components of that is Authentication.  As the official Nuxt3 Auth package is not ready what are people doing to get OIDC authentication with Nuxt3?

We are trying / looking at a few things:

- Using Express OIDC middleware - just seen this but not sure if this is just protecting what you expose by express
- Next-Auth - have found a wrapper for nuxt3 https://gist.github.com/wobsoriano/0f14bc83ad4b3e296a7e8d7d69aa55c1 - but seems experimental
- this module - https://github.com/aborn/nuxt-openid-connect - but it seems to use the implicit flow hard coded which I thought was client side only and doesn't work on the server

We are really scratching our heads here, has anyone done OIDC with Nuxt3 and could offer some direction here?

Comment: How is nuxt related to oidc? Usually there's a regular authentication (local strategy), while oidc-client-js is just a front-end script. It retrtieves some openid token through the front-end and sends it to the back-end endpoint. The back-end checks it and authenticates using the local strategy with locally generated jwt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuxt3 Authentication is now released and you should use that!

Eventually we will migrated to the official library but it came a little to late for us.

In the end as waiting for the official module wasn't an option at the time we used a patched version of https://github.com/aborn/nuxt-openid-connect as we had some additional items to handle.

Answer (score 0):

We use Apache as reverse proxy in front of Nodejs (nuxt/bridge) to provide ssl support and openid using https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc.

mod_auth_openidc puts the login credentials in a header and Nodejs (Nuxt) can pick the information from the headers.